# Android Studio Project - SMSManager not Sending SMS message

Tags: android, android-studio, sms

I've been trying to send SMS through my app without opening the deafult sms app.
But I've failed.
Here's my main code

```
 Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                    .make(recyclerView, "This will send a SMS!!!", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).setAction("Confirm", new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                    String message;
                            if(type.equals("DELIVERED")){
                                message="Order from " + data.shopz.name + " will be delivered to room  "+orders.get(clickedPosRecycler).custRoom
                                        + " in hostel "+orders.get(clickedPosRecycler).custHostel+" in 10 minutes.";
                            }else{
                            message = "Order placed at "+  data.shopz.name+" has been cancelled .Sorry for the inconvenience. An amount of Rs."
                               + orders.get(clickedPosRecycler).amount+" has been credited back to your account.";
                            }
                            orders.remove(clickedPosRecycler);
                            orderAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(clickedPosRecycler);
                            try{

                                String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
                                String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";

                                PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(thisActivity, 0,
                                        new Intent(SENT), 0);

                                PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(thisActivity, 0,
                                        new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);

                                //---when the SMS has been sent---
                                registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
                                    @Override
                                    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                                        switch (getResultCode())
                                        {
                                            case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                                                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS sent",
                                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                break;
                                            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                                                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Generic failure",
                                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                break;
                                            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                                                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No service",
                                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                break;
                                            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                                                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Null PDU",
                                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                break;
                                            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                                                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Radio off",
                                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                break;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }, new IntentFilter(SENT));

                                //---when the SMS has been delivered---
                                registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
                                                     @Override
                                                     public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                                                         switch (getResultCode())
                                                         {
                                                             case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                                                                 Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS delivered",
                                                                         Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                                 break;
                                                             case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                                                                 Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS not delivered",
                                                                         Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                                 break;
                                                         }
                                                     }
                                                 }, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));
                                SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                            smsManager.sendTextMessage("0"+ mobile, null, message, sentPI, deliveredPI);}catch(Exception e){
                                Toast.makeText(thisActivity, "SMS failed",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
            snackbar.show();
```

I've added

```
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
```

and added the permission

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.cse.pec.foodapp">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />........
```

I've tried all versions in which mobile number is of the format

 9876543210 ,+919876543210 ,09876543210 (Indian Number)

It always gives *Genric Failure*

So far I've tested on Android 4.4.4 and 6.0 and 5.1 . It fails on all.

Comment: Are you testing on actual devices?

Comment: Minimum SDK is 19 (Kitkat)

Comment: try using your local and not international code and also i would remove the "0" prefix you are always adding to the numbers you are sending the sms to.

Comment: @MikeSpike I've tried without the "0" prefix ( just the 10 digit number ) it doesn't work,but what do you mean by local code?

Comment: Your code is correct. Can you send messages to that number successfully with other SMS apps on those devices?

Comment: @MikeM. Yes I can. :(. If possible can you plz check if this code works on your device.(Its asking a lot ) but please

Comment: Yeah, it's good on my 4.4.4 device. Have you checked the value of `mobile` right before the `sendTextMessage()` call?

Comment: @Mike M. what was your  mobile number format ( don't post your exact number ,of course). I am check the value of mobile right now.

Comment: It's a U.S. number - `"1234567890"`.

Answer (score 1):

you might be using dual sim that was in my case i select which sim to use to send the message ... so i changed that in my settings

Answer (score 0):

Give the app permission to send SMS in your mobile phone.

> Go to "Settings > Apps > Installed apps > 'your_app_name' > App
>   permissions" and enable permission to send SMS.